# How to count the chinese word frequency in a tokenized list?

Tags: python, tokenize, word-frequency

I am using python 2.7.
I would like to count the frequency of words in Chinese.
How can i do this with the use of my tokenized list? I would like to locate where the sentences is in the next step. 
So, hopefully, I can count the word frequency and also give me the starting point and the ending point of each words at the same tme.

I tried to count the word frequency from the input file which is nothing to do with my tokenization. But it also give me a wrong result.
For the counter part, it shows me this : 
Counter({u'\u7684': 1}) , but my expected result is Counter({'的': 27})

```
#coding=UTF-8
userinput = raw_input('Enter the name of a file')
import codecs
f= codecs.open(userinput,"r","UTF-8")
str=f.read()
f.close()
import jieba
result=jieba.tokenize(str)
for tk in result:
        print "word %s\t\t start: %d \t\t end:%d" % (tk[0],tk[1],tk[2])
from collections import Counter
with open(userinput) as inf:
 cnt = Counter()
 for word in [u'的']:
  cnt[word] += 1
print (cnt)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct:

```
for word in [u'的']:
  cnt[word] += 1
```

You need to run your loop over the words in file:

```
for word in open(userinput,'r').read().split():
    cnt[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in [u'的']:
    cnt[word] += 1
```

This is the entirety of your accumulation loop.  You are looping over the *single character* `u'的'`.  I assume that's not what you want to do.

`Counter` works best when you feed it an iterable.  Forget this `cnt += 1` stuff, that's slow and treating the counter like a `defaultdict`.  Feed it an entire iterable at once:

```
cnt = Counter(inf.read().split())
```

It also seems like you are needlessly opening up this file a second time; since you already tokenized it above into `result`, why not just:

```
cnt = Counter(tk[0] for tk in result)
```